# requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent

Tags: push-notification

### Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent. Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.

```
var pendingIntent: PendingIntent? = null
    pendingIntent = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
    } else {
        PendingIntent.getActivity( this, System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
```

}